# Turbo C is giving me "Declaration Terminated Incorrectly" when I believe my code is fine

Tags: c, declaration, turbo-c

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int min(int a, int b);
void mergesort(int arr[],int lb, int ub);
void merge(int arr[],int lower1,int upper1,int lower2,int upper2);
void print_arr(int arr[],int arr_size);

int main()
{
 int A[15]={56,12,59,67,0,45,2,6,108,216,67,71,25,84,67};
 int lower=0;
 int upper=14;
 mergesort(A,lower,upper);
 print_arr(A,upper);
 return 0;
}

int min(int a, int b)
{
 return (a<b)?a:b;
}

void mergesort(int arr[],int lb,int ub)
{
 int i,m;
 for(m=1;m<ub-lb;m++)
 {
  for(i=lb;i<ub;i+=2*m)
  {
   int from=i;
   int mid=i+m-1;
   int to=min(i+m+m-1,ub);
   merge(arr,from,mid,mid+1,to);
  }
 }
}

void merge(int arr[],int lower1,int upper1,int lower2,int upper2)
{
 int p,q,j,n;
 int L[100];
 p=lower1;q=lower2;n=0;

 while((p<=upper1)&&(q<=upper2))
 {
  L[n++]=((arr[p]<arr[q])?arr[p++]:arr[q++]);
 }

 while(p<=upper1)
 {
  L[n++]=arr[p++];
 }

 while(q<=upper2)
 {
  L[n++]=arr[q++];
 }

 for(p=lower1,n=0;p<=upper1;p++,n++)
 {
  arr[p]=L[n];
 }

 for(q=lower2,j=n;q<=upper2;q++,j++)
 {
  arr[q]=L[j];
 }
}

void print_arr(int arr[],int arr_size)
{
 int i=0;
 printf("[");
 while(i<arr_size)
 {
  printf("{%d}",arr[i]);
  i++;
 }
 printf("]\n");
}
```

As you can see I've programmed an iterative mergesort. Now this same code with a little tweak and without the "min" function worked perfectly for the recursive one. But after I added the "min" function the code won't run in Turbo C at all when it runs on most popular online IDEs.

Example: Geeksforgeeks IDE run result: http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/GVDfs3

The university computers run Turbo C too.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `?` operator to an `if else` block ?

Comment: TurboC probably has a macro called `min`. So try calling your function something else.

Comment: Thanks @user3386109
The program works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Me reading: `Please review this code as Turbo C is...` nope

Comment: @dvhh: What for? The `?:` is being used correctly.

Comment: Off-topic. You really should **give up using Turbo C**, which is an old, unmaintained, non *standard conforming* compiler. Consider instead installing some Linux distribution on your PC, and (or) use free software standard conforming (to C99 or C11, and to C++11 or C++14) recent compilers like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)

Comment: @KeithThompson it was pointed that the issue came with the `min` function, I suspected that Turbo C is old enough to not understand that operator

Comment: @dvhh: Not a bad guess, but not likely. The `?:` operator is older than C.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

The above header is your culprit. Remove it and it should compile fine. This is because, in stdlib.h `min` and `max` are two different macros already defined for the same job and your definition is conflicting with it.

1. You can either choose use your definition by removing the `include` or use `stdlib`'s.
2. In case you need stdlib.h for any other functions and still want to use your own `min` function then simply undef the stdlib's declaration with `#undef min` immediately after `#include <stdlib.h>`

Any of these should help.

Comment: Thank you. I went on and changed the function name to minimum.

Comment: `min` and `max` are non-standard. Any implementation that defines them in `<stdlib.h>` is non-conforming .

Answer (score 2):

In fact your code is valid C.  (I'd suggest `int main(void)` rather than `int main()`, but that's a very minor point, and not what Turbo C is complaining about.) It compiles without error using gcc with warnings enabled.

Based on the other answer and comments, it appears that Turbo C defines macros `min` and `max` in the `<stdlib.h>` header. These macros are non-standard, an in fact those identifiers are available for use in user code, as you've done here. Any C implementation that defines `min` and `max` as macros in a standard header is non-conforming.

It's Turbo C's fault, not yours.

As I understand it, Turbo C is quite old and is no longer maintained, so there's probably no way to fix this error. (You could edit the header, assuming it's provided as a file, but messing around with implementation files is risky.) So renaming your `min` function is the simplest workaround.

Aside from the compilation issues, when I ran your program it produced this output:

```
[{0}{2}{6}{12}{25}{45}{56}{59}{67}{67}{67}{71}{84}{108}]
```

The array being sorted had an element with the value `216`, which does not appear in the output. The problem is in your `print_arr` function. It assumes its second argument is the number of elements in the array (`15`), but you pass it the index of the last element (`14`), so it fails to print the last element.

I haven't checked that the code is otherwise correct, but with `print_arr` fixed the output is correct at least for the input values you're using.

Some style issues:

You define `A` as an array of 15 elements, then use `14` as the index of the last element, repeating the information and making the program difficult to maintain if you want to change the length. Let the compiler count the elements for you (computers are *really* good at counting things):

```
int A[]={56,12,59,67,0,45,2,6,108,216,67,71,25,84,67};
const int len = sizeof A / sizeof A[0];
mergesort(A, 0, len-1);
print_arr(A, len);
```